# Form Displaying thank you message even when not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie at Javascript and Jquery. I have a form that I would like to submit and on submission it display a "Thank You!" message below the form. I have been able to get the form to submit into our database and display the thank you message. The only issue is that the thank you message displays regardless if the fields are filled out or not. I have tried Jquery's .show() to show a hidden div with a thank you message and the replaceWith() way also. Any help would be nice. Thanks.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#My-Form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitform();
    })

    $("#My-Form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            },
            city: {
                required: true
            },
            state: {
                required: true
            },
            zip: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
    });
});

function submitform() {
    $.post('URL', $("#My-Form").serialize(), returnResults, 'json');
    $("#MyForm").replaceWith("<p><h2>Thank You!</h2></p>");
}

function returnResults() {
    //SHOW THANK YOU MESSAGE
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so i am getting you correctly.  I think your saying the thank you message is displaying regardless of correct input.  So to prevent that, look into the jquery.validate.js method of `valid()`

in your `returnResults()` method you could do this.

```
function returnResults() {
    if ($("#mobile-landing").valid()) {
        //show thank you
    }
}
```

Comment: Where ever you edit based on a successful submit, you could perform this check (i assumed your form id was `#mobile-landing`)

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the quick response. Yes, that is the issue. The form ID is #mobile-landing even though I meant to call it #My-Form haha. I will check out the Jquery validation.

Comment: @user1240573  Did this ever answer your question?

Comment: @user1240573 make sure if this is an answer you accept it, else post the actual solution.

Comment: This answered it. Sorry for the delay on that.

Comment: @user1240573 to help me out could you "Accept" this as an answer?